# Apache2 HTTP/2 Push Service

Tags: apache2, push, http2

I have implemented **http/2 with the Push Service**.

In the header i have pushed some **Images** and **CSS** like this:

```
Header add Link "</Sale_1.jpg>;rel=preload"
```

and in my Browser i see it Pushing the Source correctly and much faster than before.

[Google Chrome Canary - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i45d.png)

But here comes the Problem: The Browser is loading the Sources twice and i don't know what is wrong.

1. Is there something that needs to be add to the html img tag?
2. Anyone working with http/2 Push that can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: It might help to see the body of the responses, both the pushed one and the one initiated by the browser

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt


Hello Frederik, i just have added this to the Push : 


`<IfModule http2_module>
<filesMatch "\.([pP][hH][pP]?)">
Header add Link "</Sale_1.jpg>;rel=preload;as=image" env=!imageloaded
Header add Set-Cookie "imageloaded=1; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly" env=!imageloaded
</filesMatch>
</IfModule>`








This checks if the IMG is already on the client, if not, then Push!
This helped me out to just Push/Load one IMG.

Thank you anyway for your help!

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt i need to switch back to show u the header. i can do it if you need it.